# Masonry, FlexSlider and infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, infinite-scroll

I'm using masinry and loading content with infinite scroll jQuery plugin, and in this content a I have differents FlexSlider slideshows. When I use the infinite scroll, the slider doesn't show correctly, the next post is positioned just in the same place, like masonry doesn't load the flexslider post..
I suppouse that the FlexSlider jQuery doesn't load well with infinite scroll. This is the code:

FlexSlider:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(\'#' . $id . '\').flexslider({
    namespace: "flex-",            
    selector: ".slides > li",
    animation: "' . $animation_effect . '",
    direction: "horizontal",            
    animationLoop: true,                
    slideshow: true,   
    slideshowSpeed:' . $slideshow_speed . ',
    animationSpeed:' . $animation_speed . ',
    pauseOnAction: true,     
    pauseOnHover: true,   
    useCSS: true,     
    touch: true,  
    video: true,  
    controlNav: false,  
    directionNav: false, 
    prevText: "",  
    nextText: "",
    });});</script>
```

Masonry + Infinite scroll:

```
<script>        
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var $container = $('#masonry-content');

            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
              $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: 'article',
                columnWidth: 1,
              });
            });

            <?php if($missiony_options['archives_infinite_scroll'] == 1) { ?>

            $container.infinitescroll({
              navSelector  : '.archive-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
              nextSelector : '.archive-nav .next',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
              itemSelector : '#masonry-content article',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
              loading: {
                  finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                  img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif',
                  msgText:'',
                }
              },
              // trigger Masonry as a callback
              function( newElements ) {
                // hide new items while they are loading
                var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
                // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                  // show elems now they're ready
                  $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                  $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
                   $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
                   $('#slider-74').flexslider();
                  });
              });
            <?php } ?>
        });


    </script>
```

The javascript is inline on the page, because I use some PHP variables. Like you can see, I append new elements to Masonry after load infinete scroll, and imageLoader and prettyPhoto, too. I have try to doing something like this with FlexSlider, but nothing. How can achieve this? Help please!

[This is the web.](http://www.codetocode-developments.com/personal/)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error - please try a debbuger

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but i'm not using Masonry.

Here's the working example of Infinite scroll + Flexslider :)

```
$('.category-product-wrapper ul.products').infinitescroll({
        loading: {
            img: templateDir+"/images/preloader.gif",
            finishedMsg: "<i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i> Content loaded.",
            msgText  : "",   
            speed: 'slow',   
                },
        animate      : false,      
        nextSelector : "ul.page-numbers a:first",
        navSelector : "ul.page-numbers",
        itemSelector : ".product-block",
        bufferPx     : 5,
    },function(){
    // callback when new content is successfully loaded in.
    $('.product-thumb .flexslider').flexslider({    
        animation: "slide",
        useCSS : false,
        slideshow: false,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true,
        controlsContainer: '.flex-container',
        });
    });
```

Basically, we need to init the slider when new content is added because Flexslider usually inits on page load.

Hope this helped! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line into:

```
 $('#slider-74').flexslider();
```

replace with

```
$('#slider-74').flexslider({

 animation: "slide"

                })
```

This initialization of flexslider have to be after masonry method.

Best Regards!